How to use storyboard instead of SwiftUI?
I created a new project and Xcode has me using SwiftUI. Can I change that to using storyboard? How can I set it to use storyboards instead of SwiftUI?

Yes, but you probably don't want to do that.
If it's a brand new project with nothing in it besides the template code, you'll have an easier time if you toss the old project and start over. Select "Storyboard" in the Interface selector on the "Choose options for your project" wizard.
Your SwiftUI-based project also has some architecture changes, moving away from the old AppDelegate to a modern App/Scene/WindowGroup approach. Unwinding that is possible but wouldn't be pleasant.
